# problem installing CorePlot

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-plot

I attempt to install CorePlot according to the readme file, but as soon as I add `$HOME/Library/SDKs/CorePlotSDK/${PLATFORM_NAME}.sdk` to **Additional SDKs** in the project settings I get a massive spew of compile errors trying to compile the PCHs.

I've followed the rest of the install procedure and I continue to see this problem with header files until i remove the path from Additional SDKs at which point the build starts working again, but of course I have no coreplot.

I'm attempting to use the 4.1 SDK. Anyone have any idea what might be happening?

I have done a "clean all" deleting the old precompiled headers.

```
ProcessPCH /var/folders/ev/eviExAoOGuKhxqFgoqkgZE+++TI/-Caches-/com.apple.Xcode.501/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/MoodTracker_Prefix-bqgeoohlnqkqawgoyuyduudrndzd/MoodTracker_Prefix.pch.gch MoodTracker_Prefix.pch normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.gcc.4_0
cd /Users/rjstone/Documents/iPhoneDev/checkout/MoodTracker
setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.0 -x objective-c-header -arch i386 -fmessage-length=0 -pipe -std=c99 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -fasm-blocks -O0 -Wreturn-type -Wunused-variable -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=20000 -isysroot /var/folders/ev/eviExAoOGuKhxqFgoqkgZE+++TI/-Caches-/com.apple.Xcode.501/CompositeSDKs/iphonesimulator-iPhoneSimulator4.1-fotsqlediwvmiughmkqdhijqmqsd -fvisibility=hidden -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -gdwarf-2 -fexceptions -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=40100 -iquote /Users/rjstone/Documents/iPhoneDev/checkout/MoodTracker/build/MoodTracker.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MoodTracker.build/MoodTracker-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/rjstone/Documents/iPhoneDev/checkout/MoodTracker/build/MoodTracker.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MoodTracker.build/MoodTracker-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/rjstone/Documents/iPhoneDev/checkout/MoodTracker/build/MoodTracker.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MoodTracker.build/MoodTracker-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/rjstone/Documents/iPhoneDev/checkout/MoodTracker/build/MoodTracker.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MoodTracker.build/MoodTracker-project-headers.hmap -F/Users/rjstone/Documents/iPhoneDev/checkout/MoodTracker/build/Debug-iphonesimulator -I/Users/rjstone/Documents/iPhoneDev/checkout/MoodTracker/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -I/Users/rjstone/Documents/iPhoneDev/checkout/MoodTracker/build/MoodTracker.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MoodTracker.build/DerivedSources/i386 -I/Users/rjstone/Documents/iPhoneDev/checkout/MoodTracker/build/MoodTracker.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MoodTracker.build/DerivedSources -c /Users/rjstone/Documents/iPhoneDev/checkout/MoodTracker/MoodTracker_Prefix.pch -o /var/folders/ev/eviExAoOGuKhxqFgoqkgZE+++TI/-Caches-/com.apple.Xcode.501/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/MoodTracker_Prefix-bqgeoohlnqkqawgoyuyduudrndzd/MoodTracker_Prefix.pch.gch

<command line>:1:1: warning: "__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED" redefined
<command line>:1:1: warning: this is the location of the previous definition
In file included from /var/folders/ev/eviExAoOGuKhxqFgoqkgZE+++TI/-Caches-/com.apple.Xcode.501/CompositeSDKs/iphonesimulator-iPhoneSimulator4.1-fotsqlediwvmiughmkqdhijqmqsd/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIPickerView.h:10,
                 from /var/folders/ev/eviExAoOGuKhxqFgoqkgZE+++TI/-Caches-/com.apple.Xcode.501/CompositeSDKs/iphonesimulator-iPhoneSimulator4.1-fotsqlediwvmiughmkqdhijqmqsd/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccessibilityAdditions.h:12,
                 from /var/folders/ev/eviExAoOGuKhxqFgoqkgZE+++TI/-Caches-/com.apple.Xcode.501/CompositeSDKs/iphonesimulator-iPhoneSimulator4.1-fotsqlediwvmiughmkqdhijqmqsd/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccessibility.h:15,
                 from /var/folders/ev/eviExAoOGuKhxqFgoqkgZE+++TI/-Caches-/com.apple.Xcode.501/CompositeSDKs/iphonesimulator-iPhoneSimulator4.1-fotsqlediwvmiughmkqdhijqmqsd/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:10,
                 from /Users/rjstone/Documents/iPhoneDev/checkout/MoodTracker/MoodTracker_Prefix.pch:13:
/var/folders/ev/eviExAoOGuKhxqFgoqkgZE+++TI/-Caches-/com.apple.Xcode.501/CompositeSDKs/iphonesimulator-iPhoneSimulator4.1-fotsqlediwvmiughmkqdhijqmqsd/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIView.h:250: error: syntax error before '^' token
/var/folders/ev/eviExAoOGuKhxqFgoqkgZE+++TI/-Caches-/com.apple.Xcode.501/CompositeSDKs/iphonesimulator-iPhoneSimulator4.1-fotsqlediwvmiughmkqdhijqmqsd/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIView.h:250: error: 'type name' declared as function returning a function
/var/folders/ev/eviExAoOGuKhxqFgoqkgZE+++TI/-Caches-/com.apple.Xcode.501/CompositeSDKs/iphonesimulator-iPhoneSimulator4.1-fotsqlediwvmiughmkqdhijqmqsd/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIView.h:250: error: syntax error before '^' token
/var/folders/ev/eviExAoOGuKhxqFgoqkgZE+++TI/-Caches-/com.apple.Xcode.501/CompositeSDKs/iphonesimulator-iPhoneSimulator4.1-fotsqlediwvmiughmkqdhijqmqsd/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIView.h:250: error: 'type name' declared as function returning a function
/var/folders/ev/eviExAoOGuKhxqFgoqkgZE+++TI/-Caches-/com.apple.Xcode.501/CompositeSDKs/iphonesimulator-iPhoneSimulator4.1-fotsqlediwvmiughmkqdhijqmqsd/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIView.h:252: error: syntax error before '^' token
/var/folders/ev/eviExAoOGuKhxqFgoqkgZE+++TI/-Caches-/com.apple.Xcode.501/CompositeSDKs/iphonesimulator-iPhoneSimulator4.1-fotsqlediwvmiughmkqdhijqmqsd/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIView.h:252: error: 'type name' declared as function returning a function
/var/folders/ev/eviExAoOGuKhxqFgoqkgZE+++TI/-Caches-/com.apple.Xcode.501/CompositeSDKs/iphonesimulator-iPhoneSimulator4.1-fotsqlediwvmiughmkqdhijqmqsd/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIView.h:252: error: syntax error before '^' token
/var/folders/ev/eviExAoOGuKhxqFgoqkgZE+++TI/-Caches-/com.apple.Xcode.501/CompositeSDKs/iphonesimulator-iPhoneSimulator4.1-fotsqlediwvmiughmkqdhijqmqsd/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIView.h:252: error: 'type name' declared as function returning a function
/var/folders/ev/eviExAoOGuKhxqFgoqkgZE+++TI/-Caches-/com.apple.Xcode.501/CompositeSDKs/iphonesimulator-iPhoneSimulator4.1-fotsqlediwvmiughmkqdhijqmqsd/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIView.h:254: error: syntax error before '^' token
/var/folders/ev/eviExAoOGuKhxqFgoqkgZE+++TI/-Caches-/com.apple.Xcode.501/CompositeSDKs/iphonesimulator-iPhoneSimulator4.1-fotsqlediwvmiughmkqdhijqmqsd/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIView.h:254: error: 'type name' declared as function returning a function
/var/folders/ev/eviExAoOGuKhxqFgoqkgZE+++TI/-Caches-/com.apple.Xcode.501/CompositeSDKs/iphonesimulator-iPhoneSimulator4.1-fotsqlediwvmiughmkqdhijqmqsd/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIView.h:256: error: syntax error before '^' token
/var/folders/ev/eviExAoOGuKhxqFgoqkgZE+++TI/-Caches-/com.apple.Xcode.501/CompositeSDKs/iphonesimulator-iPhoneSimulator4.1-fotsqlediwvmiughmkqdhijqmqsd/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIView.h:256: error: 'type name' declared as function returning a function
/var/folders/ev/eviExAoOGuKhxqFgoqkgZE+++TI/-Caches-/com.apple.Xcode.501/CompositeSDKs/iphonesimulator-iPhoneSimulator4.1-fotsqlediwvmiughmkqdhijqmqsd/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIView.h:256: error: syntax error before '^' token
/var/folders/ev/eviExAoOGuKhxqFgoqkgZE+++TI/-Caches-/com.apple.Xcode.501/CompositeSDKs/iphonesimulator-iPhoneSimulator4.1-fotsqlediwvmiughmkqdhijqmqsd/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIView.h:256: error: 'type name' declared as function returning a function
/var/folders/ev/eviExAoOGuKhxqFgoqkgZE+++TI/-Caches-/com.apple.Xcode.501/CompositeSDKs/iphonesimulator-iPhoneSimulator4.1-fotsqlediwvmiughmkqdhijqmqsd/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIView.h:258: error: syntax error before '^' token
/var/folders/ev/eviExAoOGuKhxqFgoqkgZE+++TI/-Caches-/com.apple.Xcode.501/CompositeSDKs/iphonesimulator-iPhoneSimulator4.1-fotsqlediwvmiughmkqdhijqmqsd/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIView.h:258: error: 'type name' declared as function returning a function
In file included from /var/folders/ev/eviExAoOGuKhxqFgoqkgZE+++TI/-Caches-/com.apple.Xcode.501/CompositeSDKs/iphonesimulator-iPhoneSimulator4.1-fotsqlediwvmiughmkqdhijqmqsd/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:13,
                 from /Users/rjstone/Documents/iPhoneDev/checkout/MoodTracker/MoodTracker_Prefix.pch:13:
/var/folders/ev/eviExAoOGuKhxqFgoqkgZE+++TI/-Caches-/com.apple.Xcode.501/CompositeSDKs/iphonesimulator-iPhoneSimulator4.1-fotsqlediwvmiughmkqdhijqmqsd/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIApplication.h:190: error: syntax error before '^' token
/var/folders/ev/eviExAoOGuKhxqFgoqkgZE+++TI/-Caches-/com.apple.Xcode.501/CompositeSDKs/iphonesimulator-iPhoneSimulator4.1-fotsqlediwvmiughmkqdhijqmqsd/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIApplication.h:190: error: 'type name' declared as function returning a function
/var/folders/ev/eviExAoOGuKhxqFgoqkgZE+++TI/-Caches-/com.apple.Xcode.501/CompositeSDKs/iphonesimulator-iPhoneSimulator4.1-fotsqlediwvmiughmkqdhijqmqsd/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIApplication.h:193: error: syntax error before '^' token
/var/folders/ev/eviExAoOGuKhxqFgoqkgZE+++TI/-Caches-/com.apple.Xcode.501/CompositeSDKs/iphonesimulator-iPhoneSimulator4.1-fotsqlediwvmiughmkqdhijqmqsd/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIApplication.h:193: error: 'type name' declared as function returning a function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The README instructions are for desktop apps. Follow the instructions [here](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/wiki/UsingCorePlotInApplications) to use CorePlot with an iOS app.

Comment: I downloaded http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/downloads/detail?name=alpharelease_0.2.zip&can=2&q= which doesn't appear to contain an .xcodeproj file but does contain iphoneos.sdk iphonesimulator.sdk directories. So I'm a little confused as to what this zip file is supposed to contain. I guess I'll have to get Mercurial and checkout the source to make this work?

Comment: I just downloaded the file at that link, and it has a CorePlot-CocoaTouch.xcodeproj in the Source/framework directory.

Comment: Sorry, I think I had actually downloaded an older file that didn't include the source. Anyway, with the source even when I try to build the examples I get a bunch of <command-line>: error: "__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED" redefined
<command-line>: error: this is the location of the previous definition
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1 errors. Oddly, if I just build the xcodeproj separately it builds just fine. It's only when it's built as a direct dependency that this problem occurs.

Comment: Did you undo all the changes you made when following the incorrect instructions, including removing the library folders and framework references you added?

Comment: I was actually trying to compile the examples so all of the project settings should have been correct. I rechecked them anyway. I don't get why the examples wouldn't compile the project dependency if the dependency will compile just fine on its own....

Comment: It may have something to do with the extra SDK directories you created in your Library folder.

Comment: Well, I did delete those and that didn't fix it. There could be something wrong with the sample code. I haven't tried to do this in my own project yet. Anyway, you pointed me in the right direction so I'm marking this as accepted.

Comment: Not that it helps, but I got one of the samples working pretty easily. You might try asking your question at the coreplot-discuss group. http://groups.google.com/group/coreplot-discuss

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and but when I changed the compiler to LLVM GCC 4.2 that solved the problem. If you read the instructions posted [here](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/wiki/UsingCorePlotInApplications) you will see in the comments below that someone had the same issue as you did and solved it that way too.